# Vector Valued Integration on banach space

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

I am stuck understanding the proof of existence of vector-valued Integration in S. Kesavan's book "Functional Analysis" . This [older post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3237702/applying-geometric-hahn-banach-theorem-on-vector-valued-integration) has the image of proof and the version of Hahn-Banach theorem that author uses in proving the result.
The problem I am having is that I don't understand how does the author infer $ \{m_1,m_2, \cdots m_k\}  \in K $ from $ \{t_1,t_2, \cdots t_k\} \notin K ,  \{t_1,t_2, \cdots t_k\} \neq\{m_1,m_2, \cdots m_k\} $.

I don't understand how is he arriving at this conclusion from the non-equality of these 2 tuples.  If the proof is incorrect please provide  a correct proof or a reference for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to the conclusion is that $\ \big(t_1,t_2,\dots,t_k\big)\ $ is an *arbitrary* member of $\ K^c\ $, so the inequality $\ \big(m_1,m_2,\dots,m_k\big)\ne\big(t_1,t_2,\dots,t_k\big)\ $ holds not just for some particular $\ \big(t_1,t_2,\dots,t_k\big)\ $ in $\ K^c\ $, but for *all* $\ \big(t_1,t_2,\dots,t_k\big)\ $ in $\ K^c\ $. But if $\ \big(m_1,m_2,\dots,m_k\big)\ $ is not equal to any member of $\ K^c\ $ then it cannot *be* a member of that set, and so must lie in its complement $\ \big(K^c\big)^c=K\ $.